# "This question already has an answer here:" but it is incorrect

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[How can I search for two things in a text file that both are optional but you must need at least one of them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50492774/2675154) has been closed as duplicate of [How to check if a String contains any of some strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3519539/2675154). The former question was looking for an answer using VB.NET, while the latter question is about C#.

How can answers in C# be answers to a VB.NET question? They don't help the original poster in any way. Are people not allowed to ask questions that have already been answered in another language?

Comment: The question was closed by "community" which means that the OP felt that their question was a duplicate of the suggested duplicate. However, it probably is an incorrect duplicate and instead theres probably a duplicate vb question

Comment: My original point still stands, the "answered" question does not help the original poster. Do people with privileges to close questions get more reputation for doing this?

Comment: Nope, you don't get any reputation for closing a question, its just the right thing to do when a *correct* duplicate exists. Given the OP closed their own question it probably did provide some help to them

Comment: Since the original poster accepted the duplicate it's a bold claim to state it didn't help them, but I do agree there's probably a bettter duplicate around somewhere.

Comment: I think the OP probably just accepted the "duplicate" as they were disheartened by the downvotes they were getting. The actual answer that was given on their post gave them everything they need to meet their requriements

Comment: Closing the question as a duplicate doesn't stop the downvotes from coming, although it could lead to less attention. Why would one make the assumption that the OP's attitude was an emotional response to the downvotes?

Comment: C# and VB.NET use the same framework, and their syntax isn't so hard to understand that a VB dev can't read C# code and translate it. Hell, I've done the same but in the opposite direction, and VB is a gutter language with a horrible nonsensical ludicrous syntax. And if that's too far for someone transcoders are readily available on the web. It's a non issue for these languages. Now, if we're talking about translating Lisp to brainfuck, you've got yourself a point there.

Comment: While I agree the closure of the original question, I don't think the specific questions should be closed with a general answers, if the parts what makes them more specific, are also more essential.